# Wordpress return newlines

Tags: php, wordpress

When a user searches on my wordpress site, the_excerpt is called to display the search results, however all new lines from my original post are removed. I have tried modifying the wp_trim_excerpt function, however the $text passed to this function already has all new lines removed.

Essentially, I want the_excerpt to retain new lines from my blog post when displaying the results information.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is use the_content() instead of using the_excerpt, which for all accounts strips all styling from the text,

then use a little function like this in your functions.php file

```
<?php
function truncateText($content, $chars = 150) {
    // Change to the number of characters you want to display
    $content= $content." ";
    $content= substr($content,0,$chars);
    $content= substr($content,0,strrpos($content,' '));
    $content= $content."...";
    return $content;
} 
?>
```

then in your theme, or were you want the text to apear just make a call to that function

```
<?php
  $text = the_content();
  echo truncateText($text, 250);
?>
```

hopfully should point you in the right direction..

Marty

Comment: This is a good idea, however as I mentioned it is for the search function, I could look for the search term in the text and then decide to truncate from there, but I was hoping there was an easier way to retain the new lines.

Comment: how are you displaying the results? using search.php?
or have you created a page called search and assigned a template to it? if you did you can easily modify the template to show what you want and where you want it..